# How to reduce data at reply from elastic by GET

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-webapi, elastic-stack

I quire data from elastic and I get a big bunch of information.
I would like to get only two properties with values (key value pairs): *timestamp* and *value*, but I get lots, all the other information too.
How can I require only my properties I want? I tried like I read at [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html), but I still get always to full bunch of data.

**Here my tries:**

```
            var result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>(document =>
            document
            .Source(sf => sf
                .Includes(i => i
                    .Fields(
                        f => f.Timestamp,
                        f => f.Value
                    )
                )
                .Excludes(e => e
                    .Fields(
                    f => f.ContextName 
                    )
                )
            )
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.DataRecordId)
                    .Query(search)
                )
            )
        );
```

**Or:**

```
            var result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>(document =>
            document
            .StoredFields(sf => sf
                .Fields(
                    f => f.Timestamp,
                    f => f.Value
                )
            )
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.DataRecordId)
                    .Query(search)
                )
            )
        );
```

Both return a big bag of data, much more than only *Timestamp* and *Value*.

Answer (score 0):

So I get still all properties, but the excluded ones are null. I hope I will reduce traffic this way for better performance.

I'm open to other solutions.

```
                var result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>(document =>
                document
                .Source(src => src
                    .Includes(i => i
                        .Fields(
                        p => p.Timestamp,
                        p => p.Value
                        )
                    )
                    .Excludes(e => e
                        .Fields(
                        p => p.ComponentId,
                        p => p.ContextName,
                        p => p.DataRecordId,
                        p => p.ResourceId
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                        .Field(f => f.DataRecordId)
                        .Query(search)
                    )
                )
            );
```